# How would I fix this exception when I try to delete a line from a txt and from memory?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public static void deleteEntry(String title, ArrayList<String> myLines, ArrayList<Movie> myMovieList) {
    boolean isMatch = false;
    boolean titleHasMovie = false;
    String realTitle = title;

    for (int i = 0; i < myMovieList.size(); i++) {
        String tempTitle = myMovieList.get(i).getTitle();
        isMatch = realTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(tempTitle);
        if (isMatch) {
            fileWrite myWriteFile = new fileWrite("src/Main/db.txt");
            myWriteFile.setWriteBuffer(myLines);
            myWriteFile.deleteLine(i);
            myWriteFile.saveFile();

            titleHasMovie = true;
        }
    }
    if (!titleHasMovie)
        p("Title not found");
    p("");
}
```

myLines is and ArrayList which contains

> movieTitle*year*runtime(in minutes)*actor1*actor2*director

> Iron Man*2008*126*Robert Downey Jr.*Gwyneth Paltrow*Jon Favreau

This is the exception thrown when I try to or successfully manage to delete a line

````
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at Main.Database.deleteEntry(Database.java:95)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:89)```
````

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < myLines.size() + 2; i++) {` Always smells a bit when you loop "collection_size + n". But you don't index into `myLines` at all. But you do index into `myMovieList` - but how is the size of that related to the size of `myLines` ?

Comment: Okay i was messing around earlier but that seemed to have fixed the exception for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it is throwing an out of bounds error because you are deleting entries as you are iterating. You should trying running the loop in reverse: `for(int i = myLines.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)`

Also I'm not sure why your for loops' upper bound is `i < myLines.size() + 2;` instead just .size()

Comment: so i changed the loop to `for (int i = 0; i < myMovieList.size() ; i++)` seems to get me further

Comment: @Joseph When you are deleting multiple items from an array, you should do it reverse to avoid out of bound error. For example if you have a list of 16 items, and you are about to delete 4 items. Each time you delete, the list gets one shorter, yet `i` counts to 16 still.